# Spark 3.1 - Java fails fails with an IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder error

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql

i was trying to run spark job in dataproc cluster in Google with huge dataload. Cluster is dedicated for one spark job and expecting all of cluster resources to be allocated for that job by YARN.

Spark command is configured to run 2 executers per node and 3 cores for each executor.
When the spark job is trigger YARN ResourceManager is showing only 25% of worker cores being used to containers per node.

In some point of time  Spark job is failing intermittently for heavy load due to column size limitation.

ERROR is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size 24 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632`

reference https://kb.databricks.com/sql/cannot-grow-bufferholder-exceeds-size.html

Can any one help on this, how to solve this issue in Spark?

Comment: Hi @Sweety, Can you please share the amount of memory per executor that is allocated and also, if possible, the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: My recommendation would be to think how you process your huge dataload and simply change the algorithm. You're bound by the memory a single partition (`BufferHolder`) can have and guess is that repartitioning and/or salting could be of some help.

Comment: @Vishal, It is configured  to run 2 executers per node and 3 cores for each executor. Available memory in each node is 46.92 GB so each executor uses 23.46 GB (executor memory + memoryOverhead). And Sorry i can't share the exact code that iam trying to execute :( i am applying collect_list to one of the dataset which has large number of rows and  i suspect is this trigger that error as per the reference document.(bcs result of of the collect_list(col) would be large - i guess so). can we check col size in spark-java 3.1?

Comment: **1.** Please try using the query with statistics in Spark SQL to find the column size in bytes.
`spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table AS SELECT samlpe_col FROM sample_table"); // create a new table with the specific column that you would need the size for`
`spark.sql("ANALYZE TABLE my_table COMPUTE STATISTICS NOSCAN");`
`spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED my_table").show(); // check the “Statistics” part of the output to find the column size`

**2.** Have you tried using **collect_set** instead of **collect_list**?

Comment: yes..i tried collect_set but still have same error.

Comment: If collect_set doesn’t help, it means that the column exceeds the BufferHolder limit. You could try to repartition and/or salt the dataset as suggested by @Jacek Laskowski to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, Is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As the original poster wrote, the problem is that some columns exceed the maximum limit. If you really need the columns to be bigger then I don't have any suggestions, but if not, one of the following two strategies might help.

1. In the Databricks link in the question, they suggest using *collect_set* (if you were using *collect_list* before) in case duplicates are inflating your collection/column size.
2. You can use *substr* or *substring* to arbitrarily limit your column size. If your column is a string but has a delimiter, it might be safer to find the index of the delimiter after the last entry you want and remove everything after it.