# Unable to read and a 2GB nested json with dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to read a JSON in pyspark in databricks. it is a nested JSON with multiple levels. it has one array which holds the entire data in it. I am able to process if the size of the JSOn is small like 5mb. but same code is not working for 2GB or bigger file. The structure of the json is as below. The whole data is coming into `in_network` column. it will be appreciated if can some one tell how to load this into data frame and then to a table. [The structure of JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEC3m.png)

I tried with explode the column. it is able to print the schema of the object. when I am trying to save it to table or file or if I use display  or show on the data frame, it is hanging and the job is getting failed.

below is the code I am using to read the json and explode

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,col
df = spark.read.option('multiline',True).json("/FileStore/shared_uploads/konda/SampleDatafilefrombigfile.json")
df=df.withColumn('in_network',explode('in_network'))\
        .withColumn('negotiation_arrangement',col('in_network.negotiation_arrangement'))\
        .withColumn('name',col('in_network.name'))\
        .withColumn('billing_code_type',col('in_network.billing_code_type'))\
        .withColumn('billing_code_type_version',col('in_network.billing_code_type_version'))\
        .withColumn('billing_code',col('in_network.billing_code'))\
        .withColumn('description',col('in_network.description'))\
        .withColumn('explode_negotiated_rates',explode('in_network.negotiated_rates'))\
        .withColumn('exp_neg_prices',explode(col('explode_negotiated_rates.negotiated_prices')))\
        .withColumn('exp_neg_pg',explode(col('explode_negotiated_rates.provider_groups')))\
        .withColumn('exp_npi',explode(col('exp_neg_pg.npi')))\
        .withColumn('billing_class',col('exp_neg_prices.billing_class'))\
        .withColumn('expiration_date',col('exp_neg_prices.expiration_date'))\
        .withColumn('negotiated_rate',col('exp_neg_prices.negotiated_rate'))\
        .withColumn('negotiated_type',col('exp_neg_prices.negotiated_type'))\
        .withColumn('service_code',explode(col('exp_neg_prices.service_code')))\
        .withColumn('tin_type',col('exp_neg_pg.tin.type'))\
        .withColumn('tin_val',col('exp_neg_pg.tin.value'))\
        .drop('in_network')\
        .drop('explode_negotiated_rates')\
        .drop('exp_neg_prices')\
        .drop("exp_neg_pg")
df.printSchema()
```

Comment: Hello, how big is the cluster you are using? Can you also post also the code you are trying to run? Possibly also the error you get when the job fails?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to read the json?

Comment: i have updated the code used to read the json.

Comment: Can you please also edit your question to share the error message you're getting?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder, exceeds  2147483632 bytes,

Comment: Hey @UmashankarKonda a couple of hints that could help are:
1. drop unused columns earlier in the query
2. try to understand at which line the problem happens and save to file the latest working result splitting to different partitions
Also look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847883/spark-3-1-java-fails-fails-with-an-illegalargumentexception-cannot-grow-buffe
hope this helps